# People detect using Hog not finding anyone

Tags: opencv, object-detection

I have a video of soccer in which the players are relatively far away from the camera and thus represent small portions of the image. I'm using background subtraction to detect the players and the results are fine but I have been asked to try detecting using Hog.

I tried using the detect MultiScale using the default descriptors presented on opencv but i cant get any detection. I dont really understand how can I make it work on this case, because on other sequences where the people are closer to the camera, the detector works fine.

Here is a sample image [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/404/zw43.png/)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The descriptor you use with HOG determines the minimum size of person you can detect: with the DefaultPeopleDetector the detection window is 128 pixels high x 64 wide, so you can detect people around 90px high. With the Daimler descriptor the size you can detect is a bit smaller.

Your pedestrians are still too small for this, so you may need to magnify the whole image, or just the parts which show up as foreground using background segmentation.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the function definition for detectMultiscale http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale

It might be that you need to reduced the value of `minsize` so as to detect smaller people or the people might just be too far away.

Comment: I tried setting a minsize very small and changing the scale value but it still can't detect anyone.